# Proving limit of this integral is 0 without moving limit inside?

Tags: integration, limits

Is it possible to prove that 
$$\lim\limits_{a \mapsto +\infty}\int_{0}^{1} \frac{e^{-a^2\cdot(t^2+1)}}{t^2+1}dt = 0,$$
 without moving the limit inside?

If it is ok to move the limit inside, what is the justification?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: $$e^{-a^2(t^2+1)} \leq e^{-a^2}$$